# Multiple OpenIdConnectAuthentications in ASP.NET Framework Authentication Types

Tags: owin, .net, c#

I'm trying to use two separate OpenIDConnect auth options in my ASP.NET Framework app. In my IdentitySetup I register two Auth methods:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new AuthOptionsOne());
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new AuthOptionsTwo());
```

Where both of these inherit from OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions. they then insert a unique name into the base constructor:

```
public AuthOptionsOne() : base("AuthOne") ...
public AuthOptionsTwo() : base("AuthTwo") ...
```

Then, on my constructors I'm using a CustomAttribute on my controller methods:

public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
private readonly string _authenticationType;

```
    public CustomAuthorize(string authenticationType = "AuthOne")
    {
        _authenticationType = authenticationType;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var owinContext = filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        var authentication = owinContext.Authentication;

        var identity =
            authentication.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(i => i.AuthenticationType == _authenticationType);
        
        if (identity is null || !identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            authentication.Challenge(_authenticationType);
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

My assumption here was that the authenticationtype in the identity was the same as the one in the options - It now appears it is not. The default Identity I can't use, as if I authenticate one, the other would be allowed.

My question is pretty much, how can I go about conditionally authenticating via one of these authentication types or the other?

Comment: but if you want to use "Cookies" as authentication type, how can i challenge a specific provider?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge you're facing is the differentiation between the `AuthenticationType` in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` and the `AuthenticationType` in the `ClaimsIdentity` post successful authentication.

#### Solutions:

1. **Unique ClaimsIssuer**:

   - Distinguish between the two OpenID providers using the `ClaimsIssuer` property of the `ClaimsIdentity`.
   - Set a unique `ClaimsIssuer` for each `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`:

   ```csharp
   public AuthOptionsOne() : base("AuthOne")
   {
       TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidIssuer = "UniqueIssuerForAuthOne",
       };
   }

   public AuthOptionsTwo() : base("AuthTwo")
   {
       TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           ValidIssuer = "UniqueIssuerForAuthTwo",
       };
   }
   ```

   - In your `CustomAuthorize` attribute, you can then inspect the `ClaimsIssuer` of the `ClaimsIdentity`:

   ```csharp
   var identity = authentication.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ClaimsIssuer == _authenticationType);
   ```
2. **Authentication Response Received**:

   - Set a claim during the `AuthenticationResponseReceived` notification:

   ```csharp
   public AuthOptionsOne() : base("AuthOne")
   {
       Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
       {
           AuthenticationResponseReceived = context =>
           {
               context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("provider", "AuthOne"));
               return Task.FromResult(0);
           }
       };
   }

   public AuthOptionsTwo() : base("AuthTwo")
   {
       Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
       {
           AuthenticationResponseReceived = context =>
           {
               context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("provider", "AuthTwo"));
               return Task.FromResult(0);
           }
       };
   }
   ```

   - In your `CustomAuthorize` attribute, inspect this custom claim:

   ```csharp
   var identity = authentication.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(i => i.HasClaim("provider", _authenticationType));
   ```
3. **Custom Middleware**:

   - If the above solutions don't provide the flexibility you need, consider crafting a custom OWIN middleware. This middleware can intercept the authentication process and alter the `ClaimsIdentity` as deemed necessary.

In summary, the essence is ensuring you can effectively distinguish between the two authentication providers, thereby challenging the suitable one when needed.